# Accessing the DOM from a Firefox for Android add-on

Tags: android, firefox-addon

I am attempting(and failing) to insert elements into every page visited. I am only able to insert elements into the initial page(the page displayed after the add-on has been installed). The code snippet below demonstrates this behaviour.

I have tried placing the logic that inserts the H1 element within onOpenWindow(), although that doesn't seem to make any difference.

NOTE: The code below is in addition to [template boilerplate code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/Initialization_and_Cleanup#template_code)

```
const { classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu } = Components;

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

function loadIntoWindow(window) {
  if (!window)
    return;

    window.NativeWindow.toast.show("Inserting script", "short");

   var contentWindow = window.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentWindow;
    var document = contentWindow.document;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>THIS TEXT WAS INSERTED</h1>";  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator('navigator:browser');
    while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
        var aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
        var allTabs = aDOMWindow.BrowserApp._tabs;
        for (var i=0; i<allTabs.length; i++) {
            var aContentWindow = allTabs[i].window;
        }
    }
```